# How do I replace elements in two-dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, data-science

My task is to replace all the elements whose both indexes are odd with 1, and  all the elements whose both indexes are even with -1.

Comment: That’s all very interesting. What have you tried? What have you researched?  Where *exactly* are you having difficulty?

Comment: @S3DEV I have literally no idea how to change element in array by its index's evenness

Comment: This is exactly why I asked what *research* you have done to try and figure it out.  This career path is about problem solving, rather than asking others for a solution. Our job, is to be the ones to figure it out; research and all.   :-)

Comment: @S3DEV I've looked through nearly 10 similar stackoverflow questions, pandas&numpy docs, and still couldn't achieve any progress with my task. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace elements by using a double index like: `array[y][x]` if `array` is list of lists.

This is a example:

```py
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
length = len(array)
for y in range(length):
    for x in range(length):
        if y % 2 and x % 2:
            array[y][x] = 1
        elif y % 2 == 0 and x % 2 == 0:
            array[y][x] = 0
print(array)
```

This will output: `[[0, 2, 0], [4, 1, 6], [0, 8, 0]]`

Comment: I suppose array[y][x] = 0 wasn't a typo, but an attention check :)
for anyone struggling with the same online courses i'm struggling: change it to array[y][x] = -1

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if (i%2==0 and j%2==0):
            array[i][j] = -1
        elif (i%2 and j%2):
            array[I][j] = 1
```

row => length of nested array

col => length of the array

Answer (score 1):

```
test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
def replace(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            if i % 2 and j % 2:   # checks if both indexes are odd
                test[i][j] = 1
            elif not i % 2 and not j % 2: # checks if both indexes are even
                test[i][j] = -1
    return arr

print(replace(test))  # [[-1, 2, -1], [4, 1, 6], [-1, 8, -1]]
```